# Nginx try_files for php file

Tags: php, nginx, centos

I have nginx configuration

```
location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        }

        location ~ \.php$ {
                try_files $uri /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
                include conf.d/php-fpm.inc;
        }
```

it works when i access `mysite.com/nonexistent_file.ext`, showing the content of index.php

but, accessing `mysite.com/nonexistent_file.php` (with ending `php`), show nginx 404 page.

Please help crafting the try_files rule for php file. Thank you.

UPDATE, conf.d/php-fpm.inc contains

```
location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;

        include fastcgi_params;
}
```

Update:
Solved by removing `location` tag inside the `conf.d/php-fpm.inc` file.
Thank you everyone.

Comment: Try changing `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;` to `try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;`

Comment: hello, i did try your solution, but still not working, accessing `/not_exists.php` still give nginx 404 page.

Comment: What does `conf.d/php-fpm.inc` contain?

Comment: hello, i have updated the question with the content of the file. thank you,